# Skein relation described in terms of the planar algebra of tangles

Tags: abstract-algebra, knot-theory

Wikipedia says that "More formally, a skein relation can be thought of as defining the kernel of a quotient map from the planar algebra of tangles."
Does anyone know of a resource that further elaborates on this?

Thank you

Comment: When we speak of relations in a ring or algebra (written linearly across the page), what we mean is that there is a two-sided ideal generated by the relations.  The actual elements of the algebra are cosets of this ideal in the quotient.

In the planar world, we may concatenate generators in more interesting ways than just "on the left" or "on the right," and hence, the relations (the *skein* relations) are more interesting also.  We actually want to think of the quotient by the full planar ideal generated by the skein relations.